# How to construct a json object when onclick of a button in android

Tags: android

I have 2 activities. I am switching to SecondActivity from FirstActivity. In SecondActivity I can able to add some rows, those rows contains 3 textviews & their values and images. In SecondActivity there is a button called "Done". Onclick of this button I want to create JSONObject that contains textviews values & images. Is it possible?

Please any one help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure it's possible. Implement in the onClick method the creation of the jsonObject, get your objects with findViewById(R.id.objectID), read the values you need, your jsonObject has putString() methods.